# I get a "Could not find method ?plugins() for arguments" error when running the gradle build command, what is the cause and how do I fix it?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to do an update to a microservice but when I try to build it I get this error

Could not find method ?plugins() for arguments

Why is this happening, my plugins are already declared outside of the rest of the file content and the syntax is correct.

The gradle version I am using is 6.6.

I tried checking for hidden characters as well as making sure the syntax is correct but it still doesn't build even if I just add id 'java'.